# Ada 2012 books for beginners

Tags: ada, gnat

I know that those kind of questions aren't prohibited, but anyway. I want to learn Ada 2012(I download the latest version from AdaCore so I think it's 2012), but I don't find any material in the Internet. I'm reading this http://www.pegasoft.ca/resources/boblap/book.html but I think it's outdated because there are a lot of errors in the code some of which I can't fix. If you know any free material in the Internet about Ada 2012 please give a link to it. I have also look here http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ada_Programming/Ada_2012 but this is for people who can program on Ada 2005 and they are moving to 2012. I will be very grateful to everybody who help.

Comment: You know but anyway? Very unpolite!

Comment: Well anyway, was something like "sorry but I don't know where else to ask", English isn't my first language and my metaphor sound a little bit strange I think.

Comment: Try at http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote a small intro tutorial [here](http://blog.projectpolymath.org/ada-2012-tutorial_01/) and [here](http://blog.projectpolymath.org/ada-2012-tutorial_02/), the github repo is [here](https://github.com/OneWingedShark/Ada_Tutorial)

---

As far as books go, here's John Barnes's [Programming in Ada 2012](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/110742481X).